# What does the minified jquery function "m" do?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm running a profiler on a page on my site, and the function "m" is running 1.2 seconds when I type three characters into a input masked SSN field. Trying to figure out what the function is that is being called so I can find it in the code and see why it is running so long.

One thing I have noticed is that the more elements on the page, the longer it takes to run.

Here is the function from the jquery:

```
m = function(b, e, f, g) {
    e = e || c;
    if (!g && !m.isXML(e)) {
        var h = /^(\w+$)|^.([\w-]+$)|^#([\w-]+$)/.exec(b);
        if (h && (e.nodeType === 1 || e.nodeType === 9)) {
            if (h[1]) return s(e.getElementsByTagName(b), f);
            if (h[2] && o.find.CLASS && e.getElementsByClassName) return s(e.getElementsByClassName(h[2]), f)
        }
        if (e.nodeType === 9) {
            if (b === "body" && e.body) return s([e.body], f);
            if (h && h[3]) {
                var i = e.getElementById(h[3]);
                if (!i || !i.parentNode) return s([], f);
                if (i.id === h[3]) return s([i], f)
            }
            try {
                return s(e.querySelectorAll(b), f)
            } catch (j) {}
        } else if (e.nodeType === 1 && e.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== "object") {
            var k = e,
                l = e.getAttribute("id"),
                n = l || d,
                p = e.parentNode,
                q = /^\s*[+~]/.test(b);
            l ? n = n.replace(/'/g, "\$&") : e.setAttribute("id", n), q && p && (e = e.parentNode);
            try {
                if (!q || p) return s(e.querySelectorAll("[id='" + n + "'] " + b), f)
            } catch (r) {} finally {
                l || k.removeAttribute("id")
            }
        }
    }
    return a(b, e, f, g)
};
```

Comment: Generate a source map when minifying so that you know what your code is doing.

Comment: FYI this is jquery v1.7.1

Comment: I suggest to use the unminified jQuery version and profile your code again.

Comment: You should un-minify it.

Comment: I'm not minifying. It's using the already minified jquery.min.js. It is not an environment I can substitute the un-minified version at my will.

Comment: There's entire sites dedicated to minifying/unminifying: http://unminify.com/

Comment: It would be easier to create an environment where you can substitute the un-minified version, than to try and de-minify it yourself.

Comment: @RandySlavey:  You can substitute the minified jQuery with an unminified version *right in your browser*. Don't let the server environment restrict you.

Comment: Searching the [source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js) for `isXML` reveals that the function is related to `Sizzle`, jQuery's selector engine. Unminifed source: https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/1.7.1/sizzle.js#L1150-L1233

Comment: This previous question might help: [Replace some remote javascript file with a local debugging copy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7782069/replace-some-remote-javascript-file-with-a-local-debugging-copy-using-greasemonk?lq=1)

Comment: Sorry if I sound crass, but how can you not replace the version of jQuery you're using? Simply point your HTML `<link/>` tag to the un-minified CDN version in the "Cloud". You really shouldn't use minified scripts when you're developing/debugging. You're just making your life a living hell otherwise.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not loading the jQuery in the page I'm working on. This is a large c# application using third party controls that are themselves loading and dependent upon specific versions of jQuery. While I could track down their libraries and determine where it's loading the minified jQuery and change it, I thought I'd ask here first in case anyone has run across this before. Thanks to felix-kling and @bergi for the leads towards sizzle.

Comment: You say this happens with IE8.  Is that "real" IE8 or IE11 in emulator mode?  While the emulator works well for general testing, I have noticed some odd behavior with JS that doesn't always show up in the real version. Just wanted to note that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already know that it's from jQuery 1.7.1, you can simply check its source and look out for salient patterns of the minified code, like the regexes, the `.isXML` method or one of the many DOM properties. You'll quickly find that it is the [`Sizzle` function](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.7.1/jquery.js#L5001-L5093), the entry point to jQuery's *Sizzle* selector engine.

If this function takes up too much of your running time, this might be a hint that you are a) running an old browser b) using too complicated DOM selectors c) using too many selections in your code.

Comment: It's definitely (a). Only happens this dramatically in IE8. Thanks!