# Replacing Javascript source file from server with local javascript source

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you replace a Javascript source file from server with a local javascript source file using javascript code locally without using plugins?
For example: You visit a site like `www.example.com` and you view source. In the source you find this `<script src="https://www.example.com/myscript.js?val=11111er1"></script>`
. How would you replace it with something like `<script src="C:/scripts/mynewscript.js?val=11111er1"><script>`so that the site uses "mynewscript.js" in C drive instead of "myscript.js" from server?

Comment: Why would you want to replace the path?

Comment: You can't - consider the security implications if we all started replacing websites code with our own.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [browser extension to replace JavaScript file on a live site for testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093150/browser-extension-to-replace-javascript-file-on-a-live-site-for-testing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't because the browser doesn't allows you to use computer files. While your website directory is into the drive you can use files in the same directory.